# 2d plotter witout using any packages

Tags: python-3.x

Say we have 10x10 pixels(as coordinates) and we want to plot the data. 
Before working with 10x10 instead i started off with 3x3. The point of that project is say we have coordinate(1,2) we put a start at that point. I figured to set my coordinates as dictionary. Then i used two loops. My codes are below

i get the error keyerror:0

File "/home/caglar/temp.py", line 6, in 
    if dict[i]!=j:

KeyError: 0

```
dict={1:3,2:1,3:1}
xarr=[]
yarr=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3): 
        if dict[i]!=j:
            xarr.append("") and yarr.append("")
            j+=1
        else:
            xarr[i].append("*") and yarr[j].append("*")
    i+=1
print(xarr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary, `dict={1:3,2:1,3:1}`, has keys `1`, `2`, `3`. However, you access it with `dict[i] != j`. `i in range(0,3)` means "loop through a series of `i` values starting at 0 and ending *before* 3". So it will go through `0`, `1`, `2`. This means that when it tries to access the key `0` in your dictionary it can't find it and so raises a KeyError saying that it can't find `0`.

Unrelated to your question, you also have some rather odd lines of code there which don't quite make sense:

- `for i in range(0,3)` iterates through values of `i`, so you don't have to do `i += 1` each time. In your code `i += 1` and `j += 1` don't actually do anything.
- `and` is a boolean operator. It evaluates the boolean statements on either side and tells you if both are true. Pretty much anything can be interpreted as a boolean statement so it doesn't throw an error. But when you're doing `xarr.append("") and yarr.append("")` you're telling it to evaluate each of the appends, interpret them as booleans, and return the the boolean value of `xarr.append("") and yarr.append(")`. To simply do both things you put each expression on its own line:

```
xarr.append("")
yarr.append("")
```

- `xarr.append("")` appends an empty string to the `xarr` array. If you start with `xarr = []` and then do `xarr.append("")` you'd end up with `[""]`. If you did it again you'd get `["", ""]` and so on. When you do `xarr[i].append("*")` you're saying "access the i-th item in `xarr` and then append `"*"` to it". However, since the items in `xarr` aren't arrays, you can't append to them so it will error.